# Are warning labels required by law in Washington State

Tags: health, washington, food

I'm relatively new to Stack Exchange but I figured that for the sake of my question this is the most relevant website to ask on since I am researching the health risks of energy drinks. I have searched the web for some time and have found answers pertaining to other questions of mine but I could not find a direct answer to my main question. So I ask of you, are energy drink warning labels required by law in the state of Washington?

Comment: Hi JoshuaC and thanks for your question. Your specific question seems to be related to a matter of law rather than medical sciences, so law.SE might be a better bet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no current regulation on non-alcoholic "energy drinks", though alcohol drinks containing caffeine, guarana, taurine, or other similar substances are illegal. There are regulations regarding health warnings on raw milk, marijuana. There are disclosure requirements such as the use of canthaxanthin as a coloring agent in salmonids. Otherwise there are no required warnings on food.